# Is destroying then constructing at this inside member function defined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior

### Background

I was going through some code and found a piece which is roughly like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int x;
    void do_smth()
    {
        this->~foo();
        new (this) foo{2};
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f{1};
    f.do_smth();
    f.print();
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EzwcowKZmR2MrOWz).

e.g. it destroys itself, then constructs at the point of destruction, all inside a member function. The object is used after the weird function is called. The approach was used to implement copy semantics.

Compiling both real code and example above didn't produce any warnings in gcc or clang (with `-Wall` of course). The code runs well too on -O2.

### Question

Is it undefined behavior? If not, are there any legit use cases?

---

I believe it should be undefined behavior. When destructor returns, the object is gone for good (That's what I've read on SO).

---

I've read questions about validity of `delete this`. The answer was that it is defined, but objects should not be used afterwards. I believe this is somewhat similar case, but different in having construction afterwards.

Comment: @StoryTeller, looks very close. Is there a difference in being inside a member function?

Comment: No. It used to be a popular way to reuse the copy c'tor in the assignment operator. Then constructors started throwing exceptions.

Comment: @StoryTeller, do you think the post is worth to be dupe closed? I can just delete it, but thought the title might be more googleable. My post is certainly a dupe of the one you linked though.

Comment: Duplicates are good if they are googlable. Just because it was already asked in some way, doesn't mean it's a bad post. I don't think you should delete it.

Comment: @Incomputable The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8.example-1) has a similar example :)

Comment: @Rakete1111, you could've posted that in the target question (the one StoryTeller linked), I would certainly upvote that. It seems much more solid evidence compared to existing answers.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I concur it would make a good answer. Especially if [\[basic.life\]/8.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8.3) is spun into it.